# QOpenGLContext::swapBuffers() memory leaking?

Tags: c++, qt5, opengl-3

I am working with C++ and Qt5.2 on Windows and I am using `QOpenGLContext` along with a QWindow to display a 3D scene with OpenGL.

*I Have a memory leak issue each time `QOpenGLContext::swapbuffers()` is called*

I have a class named `RenderWindow` which directly inherits from `QWindow`.
During rendering event, i execute this function :

```
void RenderWindow::doRender()
{
    if(!isExposed())
        return;

    if(!mContext)
        createContext();

    mContext->makeCurrent(this);

    //mDevice.setSize(size());

    //for(Renderer* vRenderer : mRenderers)
    //    vRenderer->render();


    mContext->swapBuffers(this);
    mContext->doneCurrent();
}
```

As 3 lignes are commented, nothing is really displayed on the screen but a black window.
This function will :

- Won't go far if the window is not exposed ;
- create a QOpenGLContext instance and configure it if it does not exist yet ;
- Make the context as current ;
- **Swap the buffers** ;
- Remove the context as being current.

The rest of the class does not do much more, juste managing a timer, initializing some data...

The issue is that this way, when I look at the Windows Task Manager, I see my program is growing 4Ko per second.
And if I comment `mContext->swapBuffers(this)`, the memory does not grow.

I checked and I enter `createContext();` only once.

I don't see where this memory comes from, but it doesn't stop.
Does anyone have any idea ?

Thank you,
/OragonEfreet

Comment: I have a similar application, I am able to reproduce this only when I have `mContext->doneCurrent();` line added. Can you try removing it, or you really need to change contexts?

Comment: Removing `doneCurrent();` changed nothing, and actually I discovered the leak before adding it. I'll try without changing context but it would be better if I could :)

Comment: 1) Try with 5.3? 2) Compile Qt (qtbase only...) in debug mode and use a memory debugger (DrMemory?) to check where the leak should be?

Comment: I'll do that, @peppe. I'll add informations once done.